# Replace values in pandas dataframe - changed functionality?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking at the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) about how to replace values in a data frame. I am copy and pasting the code directly from the documentation to do so, and it doesn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['bat', 'foo', 'bait'],
               'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})

print(df)

Result:
     A    B
0   bat  abc
1   foo  bar
2  bait  xyz

df.replace(to_replace=r'^ba.$', value='new', regex=True)

Result:
      A    B
0   bat  abc
1   foo  bar
2  bait  xyz
```

Has some functionality changed?

Comment: Share us your pandas version no. `pd.__version__` or `pip show pandas`.

Comment: pd.0.25.0 dose not work

Comment: @WeNYoBen This does work with pandas version `0.25.0`. See live code [here](https://repl.it/repls/BasicSurefootedPublishers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in pandas version `0.23.1`. If you want to install this version, use the following commands.

First uninstall pandas

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

Then install the working version.

```
pip install pandas=0.23.1
```

I have tested the code and this is the output that i got.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['bat', 'foo', 'bait'],
            'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})

>>> df.replace(to_replace=r'^ba.$', value='new', regex=True)
  A    B
  0   new  abc
  1   foo  new
  2  bait  xyz

>>> pd.__version__
'0.23.1'
```

Comment: I was using version 0.23.4.  After installing 0.23.1, it works.  Thanks!